# Yii - disabling drop down when another is selected

Tags: yii

So I have 2 `$form->dropDownList`

How can I make it in a way when if either one of the dropdown is selected, the other one gets set to value null and disabled, vice versa.

What options can I add into the `array()` so it behaves the way I want?

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use javascript or jquery, create an event handler for change event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle it via javascript or jquery. First you should define an ID for two dropdowns in this way:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($yourModel, 'attribute', CHtml::listData(...), array("id" => 'dropDown1')); ?>

<?php echo $form->dropDownList($yourModel, 'attribute', CHtml::listData(...), array("id" => 'dropDown2')); ?>
```

And in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#dropDown1").val())
      $("#dropDown2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   else
      $("#dropDown2").removeAttr("disabled");

   if($("#dropDown2").val())
      $("#dropDown1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else
      $("#dropDown1").removeAttr("disabled");

   $($("#dropDown1").on("change", function(){
       if($(this).val())
          $("#dropDown2").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
       else
          $("#dropDown2").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
   $($("#dropDown2").on("change", function(){
       if($(this).val())
          $("#dropDown1").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
       else
          $("#dropDown1").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
});
```